# Improve iteration through a long list of comparisons in an array.filter function

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, javascript-objects

I am not sure if my title appropriately expressed what I want. I basically need to filter out a bunch of items from an array of objects based on two different attributes, which need to be the same of that of another array, well... More like they need to be the same as one of the last 6 items of another array.

I am currently doing this manually, which gives me this ugly code:

```
const filteredList = list.filter(x => {
  return (
    (x.someProperty === parseInt(anotherList[anotherList.length - 1][0].someProperty, 10) && x.anotherProperty === anotherList[anotherList.length - 1][0].anotherProperty) ||
    (x.someProperty === parseInt(anotherList[anotherList.length - 2][0].someProperty, 10) && x.anotherProperty === anotherList[anotherList.length - 2][0].anotherProperty) ||
    (x.someProperty === parseInt(anotherList[anotherList.length - 3][0].someProperty, 10) && x.anotherProperty === anotherList[anotherList.length - 3][0].anotherProperty) ||
    (x.someProperty === parseInt(anotherList[anotherList.length - 4][0].someProperty, 10) && x.anotherProperty === anotherList[anotherList.length - 4][0].anotherProperty) ||
    (x.someProperty === parseInt(anotherList[anotherList.length - 5][0].someProperty, 10) && x.anotherProperty === anotherList[anotherList.length - 5][0].anotherProperty) ||
    (x.someProperty === parseInt(anotherList[anotherList.length - 6][0].someProperty, 10) && x.anotherProperty === anotherList[anotherList.length - 6][0].anotherProperty)
  )
}
```

As it is now, it is currently working, but there MUST be a better way to do this, which is what I was wanting to know. So is there a way that I can do this without having to list and make the comparissons for each item of `anotherList`?

Thanks

Comment: how long is `anotherList`?

Comment: It varies. Depends on previous operations.

Comment: As always, start with using a `function` to avoid all the code duplication!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the last six items and check against the given values.

```
const filteredList = list.filter(x =>
    anotherList
        .slice(-6)
        .some(item =>
            x.someProperty === Math.floor(item[0].someProperty) &&
            x.anotherProperty === Math.floor(item[0].anotherProperty)));
```

A slightly shorter with an array for the keys.

```
const filteredList = list.filter(x =>
    anotherList
        .slice(-6)
        .some(item =>
            ['someProperty', 'anotherProperty'].every(k =>
                x[k] === Math.floor(item[0][k]))));
```

Comment: `+` operator and `parseInt()` are not equivalent. `+` will convert `'6.66'` to `6.66` while `parseInt()` will convert to `6`.

Comment: This worked! Was about to ask what the `+` was. But all cleared now! Thanks!